# dynamic r markdown pages not showing plot and titles correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this code for a r markdown file.  page 2 is made statically and will shows SUBJECt 1 then plot(4).

Then I want to loop and create 3 more pages that show

SUBJECT 2
 img of plot 4

SUBJECT 3
 img of plot 4

SUBJECT 4
 img of plot 4

So the pages with the title SUBJECT 2 3 and 4 are dynamically created but when you run the code the titles show "# SUBJECT 3" and "# SUBJECT 4" and the plots do not show up. Can you help?

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    keep_tex: TRUE
    setspace: singlespacing
    geometry: margin=1.1cm
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE  , comment = NA, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE)

```

```{r one, include= FALSE}
ta = data.frame(group = c("A,h","b, j "),`10-20`= c(1,"-"),`34-44`= c("-","-") ,check.names = FALSE)
ta
```

\newpage
# SUBJECT 1

```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis'} 
plot(4)    
```

\newpage
```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis'} 
for(i in 2:4){    
  cat(paste0("# SUBJECT ",i) )
  plot(4)
  cat("\\newpage")
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work (with some little modification and I will explain it later). I set the code chunk options, 
`fig.keep='all'` and `fig.align='left'`, the use of first option is to save all the pictures you plot in the code chunk, the second option is to tell `knitr` to use some command to wrap up the plots so they won't mess up with other markdown codes. Whether the pictures are aligned left, center or right won't make difference except the positions of pictures, but you need to have set the option.

And you may notice that in the code, I modify `plot(4)` to `plot(i)`. Because in my experiment, `plot(4)` will only give two plots instead of three. This is not a `knitr` issue, it has something to do with `evaluate::evaluate` which `knitr` relies on. For example, if you run something like

```
r <- 'for (i in 2:4){cat(paste0("\\newpage\n # SUBJECT ",i, "\n")); plot(4)}'

rr <- evaluate::evaluate(r)
```

Then `rr` will only contain two plots. I think this is because all plots are the same in your original example. Since in your real usage, the plots shouldn't be the same (am I right?), so I guess this is okay.

````
---
output:
    pdf_document:
    toc: yes
setspace: singlespacing
geometry: margin=1.1cm
---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE  , comment = NA, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE)

```

```{r one, include= FALSE}
ta = data.frame(group = c("A,h","b, j "),`10-20`= c(1,"-"),`34-44`= c("-","-") ,check.names = FALSE)
ta
```

\newpage
# SUBJECT 1

```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis'} 
plot(4)    
```

```{r echo= FALSE, comment = FALSE, message= FALSE, warning = FALSE, results='asis', fig.keep='all', fig.align='left'} 
for (i in 2:4){    
    cat(paste0("\\newpage\n # SUBJECT ",i, "\n"))
    plot(i)
}
```
````

Comment: all the plots will likely NOT be the same but because they are it does not work?

Comment: @user3022875 There are multiple problems occurred. Setting the code chunk option `fig.align` is important for the title to display correctly. Identical plot is the cause for not showing all the plots.